# Bandwidth Selection for Kernel Density Estimation

Tags: descriptive-statistics, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

Are there any heuristics for selecting the bandwidth for kernel density estimation? In other words, is a spiky curve better or a smooth one?

Comment: It depends on what you are using the KDE for.  Do you have a specific dataset or problem setting in mind?  At https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/428083/919 I provide examples of how the bandwidth affects the KDE and how to exploit that to find modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your sample is from a continuous distribution. Then the situation is somewhat like it is for making histograms. If you have enough data, you want to choose the width of histogram bars to be just thin enough to suggest the shape of the population density curve without the 'raggedy' look that comes from neighboring bars of very different heights (maybe interspersed with some empty bins).

If the population density is multi-modal (as for a mixture of several distributions), then you don't want bars
so thick that you can't see the individual modes. [The link, provided by @whuber while I was writing this answer, pays particular attention to detecting modes.]

Using the KDE (kernel density estimator) of `density` in R,
I have found that the default bandwidth is usually about right. Sometimes I halve it and sometimes I double it, depending on the task at hand.

Sampling from a normal distribution, you may need a sample
as large as a thousand to get a useful density estimator.

```
set.seed(2921)
x1 = rnorm(500, 100, 15)
x2 = rnorm(1000, 100, 15)
x3 = rnorm(5000, 100, 15)
```

The three panels below compare R's default histogram bins,
KDE badwiths (dotted brown), and population density (blue)
for samples of sizes 500, 1000, and 5000. (Maybe the histogram at the right could use thinner bars, but eh default KDE bandwidth seems about right.)

[image]

R code for figure:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
hist(x1, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.03), col="skyblue2")
 curve(dnorm(x, 100, 15), add=T, lwd=2, col="blue")
 lines(density(x1), lwd=3, lty="dotted", col="brown")
hist(x2, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.03), col="skyblue2")
 curve(dnorm(x, 100, 15), add=T, lwd=2, col="blue")
 lines(density(x2), lwd=3, lty="dotted", col="brown")
hist(x3, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.03), col="skyblue2")
 curve(dnorm(x, 100, 15), add=T, lwd=2, col="blue")
 lines(density(x3), lwd=3, lty="dotted", col="brown")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Now we look at a bimodal population with (for simplicity, exactly) a 50:50
mixture of distributions with means sufficiently far apart
to make bimodal populations.

```
set.seed(2921)
x1 = c(rnorm(250, 80, 15), rnorm(250, 120, 15))
x2 = c(rnorm(500, 80, 15), rnorm(500, 120, 15))
x3 = c(rnorm(2500, 80, 15), rnorm(2500, 120, 15))
```

Here again, we use defaults in R. The histogram at the left
should probably have fewer bars, but the KDE bandwidth seems OK. Often, the KDE bandwidth is less 'fussy' than the width of histogram bars.

[image]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
hist(x1, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.02), col="skyblue2")
 curve(.5*dnorm(x,80,15)+.5*dnorm(x,120,15), add=T, lwd=2, col="blue")
 lines(density(x1), lwd=3, lty="dotted", col="brown")
hist(x2, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.02), col="skyblue2")
 curve(.5*dnorm(x,80,15)+.5*dnorm(x,120,15), add=T, lwd=2, col="blue")
 lines(density(x2), lwd=3, lty="dotted", col="brown")
hist(x3, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.02), col="skyblue2")
 curve(.5*dnorm(x,80,15)+.5*dnorm(x,120,15), add=T, lwd=2, col="blue")
 lines(density(x3), lwd=3, lty="dotted", col="brown")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

*Note:* If the population density has restricted support (for example, $[0,\infty)$ for gamma distributions, $[0,1]$ for beta distributions, the KDEs in R are often positive just
outside the region of support.