# Generating random variables from a mixture of Normal distributions and Exponential distribution using composition method

Tags: r, self-study, random-variable, random-generation, mixture-distribution

How can I sample from a mixture distribution in particular a mixture of Normal distributions and Exponential distribution in R using composition method?

For instance if I want to sample from:
$0.3\textrm{Exp}(1)+0.5\textrm N(0,1)+0.2\textrm N(4,1)$.

The algorithm should be following:

1. Generate random number $N$ with distribution $\left \{ \frac{a_n}{n+1} \right \}$
2. Generate random number $X$ with probability distribution $g_N(x)$. Using inverse transformation we get: $Y\sim U(0,1) \Rightarrow Y^{\frac{1}{N+1}}\sim g_N$.

I do not know understand how to get $N.$

Comment: @Xi'an yes it is, I updated my post

Comment: What is $a_n$ In 1.?

Comment: The inverse transform generation is not what you wrote.(*Hint: It is called the inverse cdf transform.)

Comment: `R` code to generate samples from a mixture of Normals appears as the `rmix` function in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/428083/919.  Here it is in its entirety: `rmix <- function(n, mu, sigma, p) {
  matrix(rnorm(length(mu)*n, mu, sigma), ncol=n)[
         cbind(sample.int(length(mu), n, replace=TRUE, prob=p), 1:n)]
}`  It is readily modified to generate from a mixture of any distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me rephrase the problem as follows:

**Question** In order to sample $X$ from $$0.3\,\mathcal Exp(1)+0.5\, \mathcal N(0,1)+0.2\,\mathcal N(4,1)\tag{1}$$

**a.** Write $\text{Prob}(X\le x)$ as
$$0.3\,\text{Prob}(X_1\le x)+0.5\,\text{Prob}(X_2\le x)+0.2\,\,\text{Prob}(X_3\le x)$$
and specify the distributions of the three random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$

**b.** Identify an integer-valued random variable $Z$ such that

1. $Z\in\{1,2,3\}$ with probability one
2. $X|Z\sim\begin{cases}X_1 &\text{if }Z=1\\X_2 &\text{if }Z=2\\X_3&\text{if }Z=3\\\end{cases}$
3. $X$ is marginally distributed as (1).

**c.** Conclude with a generation of $X$ based on the joint generation of $(Z,X)$.

Comment: Thank you I understood it completely wrong